# Hide page extenion using .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to know how can I convert url from

```html
www.mydomain.com/product.php?product-full-name&product_id=123
```

To

```html
www.mydomain.com/product/product-full-name/123
```

I know this is possible by URL rewriting in htaccess. It will great if someone show me the correct and clear way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: RewriteRule    ^product/?$    product.php   [NC,L] ,  here I can remove .php the extension, So I want to know how can i get part of url

Comment: yes  Farkie, using this i can remove only .php extension but what about other part of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**UPDATED**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/([0-9]+) product.php?$1&product_id=$2 [L]
```

If you want `www.mydomain.com/product.php?pname=product-full-name&product_id=123`
then,

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/([0-9]+) product.php?pname=$1&product_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Tuhin Subhra Mandal, I tried with RewriteRule ^product/(.*) product.php?$1&product_id=$2 [L] but this showing  404 not found

Comment: Is mod_rewrite on?

Comment: Hmm its working but my page design is gone( console error : status of 404 (Not Found)) , fine I will clear it.

Comment: I think "?product-full-name" portion is unnecessary as it is not available in $_REQUEST. Also accept my answer if it is working for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116139/discussion-between-safu-and-tuhin-subhra-mandal).